# Minimal amount of information required to define a Dihedral group?

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

Given the dihedral group $D_n$, where $r$ is a single rotation, and $s$ is a reflection, I must show that $s \circ r \circ s = r^{-1}$.

$D_n$ is a group, with properties:

1) $1 = r^0 = s^0$

2)  for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $s^k = s^{k \mod 2}$, for any $i, j \in \mathbb{Z}$, $s^{i} \circ s^{j} = s^{i + j} = s^{i + j \mod n}$

3)  for any $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, $r^k = r^{k \mod n}$, for any $i, j \in \mathbb{Z}$, $r^{i} \circ r^{j} = r^{i + j} = r^{i + j \mod n}$

With these properties alone, I have not been able to show that $s \circ r \circ s = r^{n - 1} = r^{-1}$. Thus, either I have simply not hit upon the right ideas, or additional properties are required. I suspect additional properties are required because I do not have any that talk about $s^i \circ r^j$ and $r^j \circ s^i$.

But what additional properties should I have for the Dihedral group? One idea I had:

4) for any $i, j \in \mathbb{Z}$, $s^i \circ r^j = r^t$ and $r^j \circ s^i = r^u$ for some $0 \leq t, u < n$ (since $r^k = r^{k \mod n}$ by property 3)

But this property seems too weak to give me what I am looking for. Should it be strengthened with something more specific, e.g.:

4') for any $i, j \in \mathbb{Z}$, $s^i \circ r^j = s^{i - j}$ and $r^j \circ s^i = s^{i + j}$

What is the minimal amount of information needed to define a dihedral group purely algebraically?

Comment: Yes, you need more properties than 1), 2) and 3), since those three properties don't allow you to exclude the case of the (abelian) group $C_2 \times C_n$, which of course does *not* satisfy $srs = r^{-1}$. But your properties 4 and 4' don't hold: composing a reflection with a rotation does not give a rotation.

Comment: Why not require that $s \circ r$ also be a reflection?

Comment: @darijgrinberg yes, that is a typo! i will fix it

Comment: @JoshB.i had a typo in 4', should be fixed now

Comment: The usual extra information is $srs=r^{-1}$ (which, unfortunately, is what you are trying to prove).

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.  If you're just trying to solve the problem you stated at the start, the path you are going down is totally useless.  Whatever additional "properties" you come up with would still be properties you would have to _prove_ really are true for a rotation and a reflection, and proving that would surely be more work than just directly proving $s\circ r\circ s^{-1}=r^{-1}$.

Comment: (Here I am assuming that your definitions of the "rotation" $r$ and "reflection" $s$ are geometric.  If you have a different definition, you need to tell us what your definition is, since any properties of $r$ and $s$ need to somehow be derived from their definition.  As Gerry Myerson said, if one is making a purely algebraic definition, then usually $srs=r^{-1}$ is itself part of the definition.)

Comment: @EricWofsey It's good to know that $srs = r^{-1}$ is itself part of the definition, because it means I might be misunderstanding the question I am trying to answer (which asks: show that $srs = r^{-1}$ where $r$ is a rotation in the plane, and $s$ is a reflection in the x-axis). It could be that the question literally wants me to use 2D geometry to show this is the cas?

Comment: Yes, if the problem refers to rotations and reflections in the plane, it is literally asking you to prove that these particular geometric transformations satisfy $s\circ r\circ s^{-1}=r^{-1}$.